# Program to print duplicate values of array only once in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

int array[5]={3,3,3,3,1,1};

output:
3 1

I am unable to do this, please help me out. I tried 2 for loops with boolean check , it didn't work.

```
  int main()
  {
    int a[5]={3,3,3,1,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    for (int i =0 ; i<n; i++){
       bool checked=true;
          for (int j=0 ;j<i; j++){
                 if(a[i]==a[j]){
                  bool checked=false;
        }
    }
    if(checked==true){
        cout<<a[i]<<",";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Comment: If you post the code you tried, then someone will help you fix it, or explain what is wrong with it. You will learn more that way. There's not much to be learned if someone just writes the code for you.

Comment: Two for loops with a boolean check is one way to solve this problem, so you were probably quite close. Let's see your code!

Comment: Simple mistake. `bool checked=false;` is incorrect, you are redeclaring the `checked` variable. Change to `checked=false;`

Comment: @karan "It didn't work" is not a useful problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I used a function to remove duplicate values from the array and then printed the array without the duplicates. I don't have boolean functions.

```
int removeDuplicate (int arr[], int size) {
    if (size == 0 || size == 1) {
        return size; 
    }
    int* temp = new int[size]; /* Create a temporary
    array with size*/
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            temp[j++] = arr[i]; //strore element if its unique
        }
    }
    temp[j++] = arr[size - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i]; //modify the existing array
    }
    return j; //j is the new size for the array without duplicates
}

int main(){
    int arr[5] = {3,3,3,1,1};
    
    int size = removeDuplicate(arr, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ; ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please note `bool checked=false;` you are defining again checked variable.

Please see the fix.

```
  int main()
  {
    int a[5]={3,3,3,1,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    for (int i =0 ; i<n; i++)
    {
       bool checked=true;
        for (int j=i+1 ;j<n; j++)
        {
            if(a[i] == a[j])
            {
                checked=false;
            }
        }
        if(checked == true)
        {
            std::cout<<a[i]<<",";
        }
    }
}
```

output : 3,1,

Even you can do it in a better way with `std::unique` algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::unique, std::distance
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  int a[5]={3,3,3,1,1};         // 3 3 3 1 1
  std::vector<int> myvector (a, a+5);

  // Sorting the array 
  std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end()); 

  // using default comparison:
  auto it = std::unique (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());   
                                                        

  myvector.resize( std::distance(myvector.begin(), it)); 

  // print out content:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

output : myvector contains: 3 1